# How do I vertical align my divs using flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, frontend

Basically, I'm practicing HTML & CSS using flexbox and I cannot set my navigation menu and logo vertically. I've using align items, but nothing.

This is how it currently looks:

[image: Current website image]

As you can see, it looks uneven, the "brand" logo looks upper than my nav menu. How should I fix it?

This is my code:

```css
/* General selector*/

* {
  margin: 0%;
  padding: 0%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  background: #f2f2f2;
}


/*General selector ends*/


/* header*/

.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 800px;
}


/*nav bar*/

.logo {
  margin: 20px;
}

.logo a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 45px;
}

.nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.nav a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.nav li {
  list-style: none;
}

.nav a:hover {
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Home</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>

<body>

  <!--header-->

  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="logo"><a href="index.html">Brand</a></h1>

    <ul class="nav">
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Latest news</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <!--header ends-->

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: the typo of "container" in css might be an issue as well

Answer (score 1):

```css
* General selector*/
*{
    margin: 0%;
    padding: 0%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    background: #f2f2f2;
}
/*General selector ends*/

/* header*/

.container{
    display: flex;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 800px;
    
}

/*nav bar*/
.logo{
    margin: 20px;   

}

.logo a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font-size: 45px;
    
}
.nav{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center
    
}
.nav a{
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.nav li{
    list-style: none;   
}

.nav a:hover{
    color: gray;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>

<!--header-->

<div class="container">
    <h1 class="logo"><a href="index.html">Brand</a></h1>

<ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Latest news</a></li>
    
</ul>
</div>

<!--header ends-->
    
</body>
</html>
```

Add to container style and nav, `align-items: center`

```
.container{
    display: flex;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 800px;
    align-items:center;        
}
.nav{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center

}
```

Comment: Doesn't work...

Comment: Sorry, you have add to .nav also, align-items: center, i've changed post and add a spinnet to check results

Answer (score 0):

You can change your CSS to be more simple. What you need to do is change the container to allow space between logo and nav - using `justify-content: space-between;` attribute in your container.

Changing the style of font, margin and padding to be more concise.

Using `align-items: center;` attribute for logo and nav as suggested by **@Aloiso Junior**.

CSS + HMTL

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Home</title>

  <style>
        * General selector*/
    * {
        margin: 0%;
        padding: 0%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    body {
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 16px;
        background: #f2f2f2;
    }
    /*General selector ends*/

    /* header*/

    .container {
        display: flex;
        max-width: 800px;     
        justify-content: space-between; 
    }

    /*nav bar*/
    .logo {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center; 
    }

    .logo a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: black;
        font-size: 45px;
        
    }
    ul.nav {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;  
    }
    .nav a {
        color: black;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .nav li {
        display: block;
        margin: 0 0.2rem;
        padding: 0.5rem;
    }

    .nav a:hover {
        color: gray;
    }

  </style>

</head>

<body>

  <!--header-->

  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="logo"><a href="index.html">Brand</a></h1>

    <ul class="nav">
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Latest news</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <!--header ends-->

</body>

</html>
```

Hope this helps clean it up a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, guys. .container was bad and I added a space between.

```
/* General selector*/
*{
    margin: 0%;
    padding: 0%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    background: #f2f2f2;
}
/*General selector ends*/

/* header*/

.container{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content:space-between;
}
/*nav bar*/
.logo{
    margin: 20px;      
}

.logo a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font-size: 45px;
}

.nav{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.nav a{
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
    
}

.nav li{
    list-style: none;   

}

.nav a:hover{
    color: gray;
}

/*nav bar ends*/




/* header ends*/
```